# in socket.current?.readyState !== WebSocket.OPEN what is the meaning of "?."

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

```
  const onConnect = useCallback(() => {
    if (socket.current?.readyState !== WebSocket.OPEN) {
      socket.current = new WebSocket(URL);
      socket.current.addEventListener("open", onSocketOpen);
      socket.current.addEventListener("close", onSocketClose);
      socket.current.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
        onSocketMessage(event.data);
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

I am trying to connect to WebSocket and I have to use sockent.current?.readyState but not socket.current.readyState .
What is the usage of extra "?" in this code ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining